# MPMoviePlayer stuck on "loading..."

Tags: ios, avfoundation, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am initializing a new MPMoviePlayerViewController with an URL to play fullscreen video from a server. After the player screen appears, it stucks on "Loading...", but no actual loading is taking place, cause there is no network communication at all for some reason. I use this code:

```
- (IBAction)playerButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                  @"http://ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *c = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                      initWithContentURL:url];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:c];
}
```

URL is correct and this what I get:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly on my machine. The problem is not reproducible.

Perhaps in your case something is stopping the Simulator from making a network connection. It might be LittleSnitch; the network might be down; there are lots of possibilities.

You are effectively tunneling the Simulator's networking through your computer's networking. I suggest that you run the code on a device rather than the Simulator, in order to avoid this complication.

Comment: Thank you! Has been debugging this code for about 30 mins and couldn't find any error! Will debug network stack...

Comment: By the way, if you can run on iOS 8 only, you should migrate away from MPMoviePlayerViewController and use AVKit instead.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this idea firstly, but the app has to be supported on iOS 7+

Comment: I understand, of course. I was just making sure you knew that AVKit existed. :)

Comment: Is solved the problem - it was just a bug in a simulator. Safari was not able to open pages too. After I've restarted the simulator, everything started to work fine.
Thank you for the help and testing my code.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for reporting back. I guess the Simulator sometimes gets "wedged"... In general, though, I find that certain classes are best tested on a device, and MPMoviePlayer is one of them.

Comment: After a long time has passed... Seems that network stack of the simulator stops working after sleep / wake cycle of a laptop.